# Move status bar to the right in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I use a web site which has a very important part there, hidden behind the status bar when it appears. It drives me crazy to have to put the mouse pointer over it to be able to read what's behind. Is it possible to move it to the right? Sometimes it goes to the right automatically.

Comment: Try telling the webmaster. Having a web page bleed to the edges with text is considered a bad practice nowadays.

Comment: @digitxp: I don't think they are doing anything wrong: http://webchat.freenode.net

Comment: I think the problem there is that the widget they're using, IIRC it's qIRC, is designed to be run from an embedded iframe, where as here they're running it full screen.

Comment: Try keeping the mouse cursor off of any links (eg in the corner of the screen). Failing that, you could file a request to be able to set it to default to the right, on the Chromium project tracker (http://code.google.com/p/chromium/) since there is not currently one (for some reason).